# how to create a class in android studio thats parallel table in backendless

Tags: android-studio, backendless

how do i get a field type pointer  from backendless table into a class (object) in android studio
Building building = (Building) Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser().getProperty("building");

Comment: what do you mean `thats parallel table in backendless`? have you registered your classes? are you using relationships? are they set to autoload? you've given very little information in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Backenldess Code Generation tool.
Steps:

1. Select "Code Generation" in console
2. Select IDE
3. Select "Java classes for defined data tables" checkbox
4. Download generated code
5. Open downloaded project in Android Studio

*See screenshot below:*

[image: Tools]

Comment: thanks so much but how do i add it to my existing project?

Comment: You can copy java files preserving package structure.